# Plain Greek yogurt with finely chopped green onions dip

Tags: onions

I am doing a 21 day challenge and I am making a Greek yogurt and finely chopped green onion dip and I need something to subsitute green onions with. What can I use that is very similar to it?

Comment: @elmercat, I saw no purpose in this comment but to answer the question. Answering in comments is worse than writing nothing at all - we'd all love you to see posting a complete answer, but the comment had to go one way or the other.

Comment: Why do you need to substitute the onions? Do you have an allergy or do you simply not like them? Or do you not have any? We can help you better if we know why you can't use the green onions.

Answer (score 1):

Chives or scallions would substitute nicely.

Garlic, shallots for a bit more flavor.

The trinity always works good; - onion, celery and green pepper.  And of course fennel for a twang.

onion celery and carrot is another classic.

asofetida maybe?  for something weird.

Comment: Those are good choices but technically scallion is green onion

Answer (score 1):

Lots of fresh or dried dill is very nice in greek yogurt.

Comment: Dill is _fantastic_ in greek yogurt! :)